# Is there a way in R to convert the following character variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have the following dataframe with a character variable that represents the number of lanes on a highway, can I replace this vector with a similar vector that has numbers instead of letter?

```
df<- structure(list(Blocked.Lanes = c("|RS|RS|ML|", "|RS|", "|RS|ML|ML|ML|ML|", 
"|RS|", "|RS|RE|", "|ML|ML|ML|", "|RS|ML|", "|RS|", "|ML|ML|ML|ML|ML|ML|", 
"|RS|ML|ML|"), Event.Id = c(240314L, 240381L, 240396L, 240796L, 
240948L, 241089L, 241190L, 241225L, 241226L, 241241L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The output should be something like df2 below:

```
df2<- structure(list(Blocked.Lanes = c(3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 6L, 3L), Event.Id = c(240314L, 240381L, 240396L, 240796L, 
240948L, 241089L, 241190L, 241225L, 241226L, 241241L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to count number of `"|"` in each string. We subtract it with `- 1` since there is an additional `"|"`.

```
stringr::str_count(df$Blocked.Lanes, '\\|') - 1
#[1] 3 1 5 1 2 3 2 1 6 3
```

In base R :

```
lengths(gregexpr("\\|", df$Blocked.Lanes)) - 1
```

---

Another way would to be count exact words in the string.

```
stringr::str_count(df$Blocked.Lanes, '\\w+')
lengths(gregexpr("\\w+", df$Blocked.Lanes))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as succinct as @Ronak Shah's, but another method in Base R.
String split on string literal `"|"` and then count elements:

```
df2 <- transform(df, Blocked.Lanes = lengths(Map(function(x) x[x != ""], 
               strsplit(df$Blocked.Lanes, "|", fixed = TRUE))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ronak's solution you could also do:

```
 stringr:str_count(df$Blocked.Lanes, "\\b[A-Z]{2}\\b")
```

if the lanes are always 2 letters long, or

```
 stringr:str_count(df$Blocked.Lanes, "\\b[A-Z]+\\b")
```

if the lanes are always at least one letter long.

```
 stringr:str_count(df$Blocked.Lanes, "(?<=\\|)[A-Z]+(?=\\|)")
```

also works.